# RPI(2) Bare Metal: does GPU support text mode and what is the default video mode?

Tags: pi-2, gpu, bare-metal

I'm struggling with trying to find any information about text-mode capability in Raspberry Pi. I'm reading about decompression, 3d, etc. fancy features but I'd like to learn about fundamentals:

1. Is there something like old, good text mode, where one video memory byte represents one character?
2. What is the default video mode after powering up?
3. What text mode resolutions are available (if any) and how to switch them?